# File upload on a server at a specific location using servlets?

Tags: java, servlets

Hi people I have a serious problem at hand, I have a zip file on a client machine and I need to upload that zip file on the server machine on a specific location, the client machine automatically creates a zip file of the snapshots and should upload that zip file programatically on the server on a particular location and there is no user interaction whatsoever in between, Can anyone suggest how to go about this task. I need to write a java code for the same. I have tried several links that demonstrate file uploading but none was able to serve my purpose.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by " none was able to serve my purpose." . Any code examples?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) in your client, you can find many examples to make the client able to upload a file as multipart post http request.

Then you have to create a simple servlet able to receive the file as stream.
To help you with the servlet implementation there is another lib you can use: [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)

Answer (score 1):

Receive and save a file in a multipart post with Servlet 3.0 API, without using any external lib. :

First you must upload the file via 'Post' with multipart enable, because is the more convenient way to upload big files. you must name the 'part' 'file'. Each part have headers. The code reads the header to use the original filename or set one according the upload time. The code write a simple text to confirm the upload request.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@MultipartConfig
public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        Part part = request.getPart("file");

        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("filename=\"(.*)\"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(
                part.getHeader("content-disposition"));
        String filename;
        if (m.find()) {
            filename = m.group(1);
        } else {
            filename = "upload" + System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        part.write("C:/path/" + filename);
        out.println("File '" + filename + "' uploaded.");
    }
}
```